# Cannot use .append after .empty() on select

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I'm trying to add options to a  dynamically, just like in the example given here:https://github.com/google/google-apps-script-samples/tree/master/simple_tasks
I use almost the exact code but I get an error everytime:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property length of [object Object]
>   which has only a getter

my code.gs:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE).setTitle('RepairAdminSysteem');
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function data() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SS_ID).getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(data));
}

function init() {
  var status = ['VERSTUURD','NIET VERSTUURD','AKKOORD','NIET AKKOORD','HERRINNERING','TWEEDE HERRINNERING','GEEN REACTIE','NIET VAN TOEPASSING','PAUZE'].sort();
  return status;
}
```

my (relevant)html:

```
<select id='status' disabled>
  <option>Loading...</option>
</select>
```

and the javascript:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#status').bind('change', loadPO);
    start();
   });


  function start() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success)
      .init();
    }

  function success(status) {
    var select = $('#status');
    select.empty();
    status.forEach(function(elem) {
      var option = $('<option>').attr('value',elem).text(elem);
      select.append(option);      
    });
    select.prop('disabled', false);
    loadPO();
  }

  function loadPO() {
    alert('test');
  }

</script>
```

If I change the `select.empty();` to `select.html('');` everything works as expected, but I don't understand why it is working in the simple tasks example and not in my code.

What i want to know is why is this, almost identical code, working in the simple task app in the link above and not in my app?

Comment: Which line does that error refers to?

Comment: In the console it says line 66, but that is after Caja sanitation and sandboxing: http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/

Comment: Sorry but Caja is where? while line in the code you posted?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Your code works perfectly for me when using jQuery 1.8.3.

Comment: I'm using 1.10.2. Strange it works for you, as far as I know nothing changed with .empty() between those versions.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
       function success(status) {
            var select = $('#status');
            select.html('');
            var option = '';
            status.forEach(function(elem) {
              option = option + '<option value="'+elem+'">'+elem+'</option>';
            });
            select.append(option);      
            select.prop('disabled', false);
            loadPO();
        }
```

empty will also work check below code

```
        jQuery(function(){
            var select = $('#status');
            //select.html('');
            select.empty();
            var option = '';
          option = option +  '<option value="sad">sdasd</option>';
          option = option  + '<option value="avvsad">sdavvsd</option>';
          option = option   +'<option value="vvv">svvvdasd</option>';
          select.prop('disabled', false);
            select.append(option);      
        })
```

HTML CODE

```
    <select id='status' disabled>
          <option>Loading...</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function success(status) {
            var select = $('#status');
            var option = '';
            status.forEach(function(elem) {
              option = option  '<option value="'+elem+'">'+elem+'</option>';
            });
            select.html(option);      // here html reset by new option
            select.prop('disabled', false);
            loadPO();
        }
```

reference **[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**

Comment: I know this is working, my example also works when I change .empty() to .html(''). I just dont understand why it is working here: https://github.com/google/google-apps-script-samples/tree/master/simple_tasks and not in my code.

Comment: let me check @user2890449